# Alternative to Python string replace method

Tags: python, string

I want to delete certain words from a paragraph, such as "and", "as", and "like". Is there an easier way to delete words from a string than doing it via replace --

```
new_str = str.replace(' and ', '').replace(' as ', '').replace(' like ', '')
```

For example, is there a method similar to the following?

`str.remove([' and ', ' like ', ' as '])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you could use the `sub` function from the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'I like this as much as that'
>>> re.sub('and|as|like', '', s)
'I  this  much  that'
```

Comment: ... but if you care even the slightest bit about performance, you won't do it with a regular expression if it's this simple a rule. (Not that you need to worry about performance in general - but this is an obvious sort of case where the statements about premature optimisation don't apply; `str.replace` is known to be oodles faster than `re.sub`.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: very good observation! I thought about that too, but the OP said something else than `replace`, so I was forced to look for another (worse performance) solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions:

```
    >>> import re
    >>> test = "I like many words but replace some occasionally"
    >>> to_substitute = "many|words|occasionally"
    >>> re.sub(to_substitute, '', test)
    'I like   but replace some '
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do without regex. See the following example

```
def StringRemove(st,lst):
    return ' '.join(x for x in st.split(' ') if x not in lst)

>>> StringRemove("Python string Java is immutable, unlike C or C++ that would give you a performance benefit. So you can't change them in-place",['like', 'as', 'and'])
"Python string Java is immutable, unlike C or C++ that would give you a performance benefit. So you can't change them in-place"

>>> st="Python string Java is immutable,     unlike C or C++ that would  give you a performance benefit. So you can't change them in-place"
>>> StringRemove(st,['like', 'as', 'and'])==st
True
>>>
```

Comment: Note that this will destroy multiple spaces in a row and will turn `\r`, `\n` and `\t` into space as well. If you care about spaces, use `st.split(' ')` instead of `st.split()`. Also, the square brackets around the `join()` body aren't neat. I'd scrap them and make it a generator expression (which for larger inputs will use less memory, also) instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tweaked it a little so now it will work with multiple spaces and other separators. I have also changed the List to generator.

Comment: Your change has made it so that tabs and newlines no longer act as word separators, so words won't be eliminated if, e.g., they occur after a tab.

Comment: I think I will delete my answer as I can't find any other feasible way to do without regex as you can't specify multiple separators in split. Unless you have anything in mind

Comment: I wouldn't delete this answer! For some problems, there might not be tabs or newlines, so this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Abhijit: when a generator expression is the sole argument to a function, you don't need the extra parentheses.

Comment: Would be good to turn `lst` into a `set` first, to make the lookups O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Note that if all you care about is readability and not necessarily performance, you could do something like this:

```
new_str = str
for word_to_remove in [' and ', ' as ', ' like ']:
    new_str = new_str.replace(word_to_remove, '')
```

Comment: Why, do you you it would impact performance badly ?

It seems to me like it would be close to equivalent to the substitute method and way more efficient than the regular expressions method.