# Replacing replaces in a faster way

Tags: python, python-re

I'm filtering lots of tweets and while I was doing tests on how to filter each character I ended up with this:

```
x = open(string, encoding='utf-8')
text = x.read()
text = re.sub(r'http\S+' + '\n', '', text, )
text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', text,)  # removes links
text = re.sub(r'@\S+' + '\n', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'@\S+', '', text)  # removes usernames
text = text.replace('0', '').replace('1', '').replace('2', '').replace('3', '') \
    .replace('4', '').replace('5', '').replace('6', '').replace('7', '').replace('8', '').replace('9', '') \
    .replace(',', '').replace('"', '').replace('“', '').replace('?', '').replace('¿', '').replace(':', '') \
    .replace(';', '').replace('-', '').replace('!', '').replace('¡', '').replace('.', '').replace('ℹ', '') \
    .replace('\'', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('   ', '').replace('  ', '').replace('”', '') \
    .replace('º', '').replace('+', '').replace('#', '').replace('\n', '').replace('·', '\n')
text = remove_emoji(text).lower()
x.close()
```

Which was useful because I could test many things but now I think that I'm not going to modify this anymore so it's ready to be optimized, how could I make it faster? All the replaces replace with nothing except .replace('·', '\n')

Comment: How about `.strip(chars)`

Comment: Question related to improving efficiency of your code are more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: Why are you separately matching https followed by a newline? The next expression will match them too.

Comment: @Peter doesn't do the same as my replaces

Comment: @Peter it only strips from the beginning (maybe also the end), but not all characters mid-text.

Comment: @theheavycoder Oh yeah haha, bit of a brain fart, I thought something felt a bit off

Comment: How fast is it right now, specifically, and how fast do you need it to be before it is acceptably "faster"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve most of this with string `maketrans` and `translate` methods - they let you define a mapping from any single char to any given string

```
s = "asd123.?fgh"

translations = {"1":"", "2":"", "3":"", ".":"\n", "?": ""}
print(s.translate(s.maketrans(translations)))
```

It will do all the changes in a single pass through the string, making it much faster.

Comment: Are you avoiding `maketrans`'s power on purpose or did you just not read its documentation?

Comment: Both? Passing 3 arguments means you can only replace with equal length strings. Sure it works in this case but I prefer dictionary as more flexible and explicit

Comment: Then I guess I'd show both versions, this one for generality and the other because it's much nicer and the generality isn't needed here. Btw your single-char vs `\n` doesn't make sense, as that *is* a single char (not in the source code, but in the actual value).

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily faster, but way easier to read would be something like this:

```
for char in "#<>$+%!&`*|?=/{}:\\@ ';." + '"':
    string = string.replace(char, '')
```

Comment: instead of `+ '"'` you could escape the quotation char -> `\"`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski or you can use triple quotes to avoid escaping both " and ' - `'''#<>$+%!&\`*|?=/{}:\\@ ';."'''`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8373426/16467184).
The `re` module (should already be installed in python) seems to work.

For example,

```
import re
string = "abccbdac"
re.sub('b|c', '', string) #ada
```

In this case, running `re.sub('b|c', '', string)` would return "ada". The pipeline is used as a separator between characters to replace.